# ESP8266 Wifi.setOutputPower - original/default value?

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I'm working on dynamically adjusting the ESP8266 WiFi power using the following function, such that it's as low as possible, yet sufficiently reliable:

```
WiFi.setOutputPower(x)
```

I've been trying unsuccessfully to find out what the original/default value is before that function is called? There is no function WiFi.getOutputPower(). I know the range of values is 0 to 20.5, but I'm curious to know what it is initially? I guess it could depend on the particular Arduino? I have the following: ESPduino, Wemos D1R2/D1R1/D1R1 mini, NodeMCU, Yun sheild.

I plan to use iwconfig & iwlist on a Pi3 to measure the RSSI, but I'd like to know the baseline if possible.

The best similar idea is expressed in here: : [How to optimise TX power for ESP8266?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/45351/how-to-optimise-tx-power-for-esp8266/)

Thanks in advance ;-)
Geoff

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same answer. I found this link: https://gitlab.com/painlessMesh/painlessMesh/issues/51

Someone dug deeper into the code and found it's set to the max value on init